# Symfony2 How to create one form for many the same entities?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, formbuilder

I have the following entity:

```
// ZaquPL/MyBundle/Entity/Task.php
protected $name;
protected $order;

public function getName()         {...}
public function setName($name)    {...}
public function getOrder()        {...}
public function setOrder($order)  {...}
```

I would like one form with many entities. It's becouse I want to sort tasks "drag and drop) and change their names in one form, with one submit button and without AJAX.

It should looks like in that schema:

```
[GRAB AND MOVE <INPUT name="order[1]">] <INPUT name="name[1]">
[GRAB AND MOVE <INPUT name="order[2]">] <INPUT name="name[2]">
[GRAB AND MOVE <INPUT name="order[3]">] <INPUT name="name[3]">
[GRAB AND MOVE <INPUT name="order[4]">] <INPUT name="name[4]">
[GRAB AND MOVE <INPUT name="order[5]">] <INPUT name="name[5]">
[GRAB AND MOVE <INPUT name="order[6]">] <INPUT name="name[6]">
```

I know how to create view, how to use jquery UI drag and drop components etc, so don't worry about that. I only ask how to create this form using Symfony FormBuilder. Have you any idea?

Comment: The formBuilder is made to hande only one form for a type, but you can do it manualy in your twig template

Comment: @elkorchi anas: So... have you any solution or example for me?

Comment: You can use one form build just with html this form will contain all your entities and you can use theme like an array so in the server side you will get an ordered array of your entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want create a collection of form : [doc](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).
On the first persistence the order is defined by your request header order. But if you edit this collection you can't just submit another order and persist.
To change your collection order you can :

- remove last collection on edit and persist the new collection
- use an attribute which manage your order
- serialize your collection(a little creepy i know)

I hope it help